# Jackson JSON ObjectMapper adding a 'new' property

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I'm just trialling the Jackson XML ObjectMapper for my application.

I wrote this small class. So at the end it prints back the deserialized object. Which is okay, except for the objects at each level it prints a new property called "new": true.

I'm not sure where it's coming from. The object is a spring jpa entity.Is this property something that Spring introduces? It's definitely not a property on the class as I can't read the object string back in until I remove the new property.
e.g

```
lastModifiedDate":null,
"createdBy":null,
"new":true
},
```

This is the code:

```
/**
* Updates the layout from a JSON String in the format for the layout definition file
* @return
*/
public Layout updateFromJSONString(String jsonString)
{
    logger.entry(jsonString);

    Layout layout = null;
    try {
        layout = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Layout.class);
        logger.exit(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(layout));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }


    return layout;
}
```

And the base entity which, if any, would be causing the problem - there are 2 other subclasses with just simple properties, all objects including the nested objects inherit from this base class:

```
public class AbstractAuditableEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Auditable<SystemUser, Long> {

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String externalIdentifier;

    @Basic
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateConstants.DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT)
    private DateTime lastUpdated;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SystemUser lastUpdateUser;

    @Basic
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateConstants.DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT)
    private DateTime created;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SystemUser createUser;



    /**
     * Gets created by audit user.
     */
    @Override
    public SystemUser getCreatedBy() {
        return createUser;
    }

    /**
     * Sets created by audit user.
     */
    @Override

    public void setCreatedBy(SystemUser createdBy) {
        this.createUser = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Gets create audit date.
     */
    public DateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    /**
     * Sets create audit date.
     */
    public void setCreated(DateTime creationDate) {
        this.created = creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Gets last modified by audit user.
     */
    public SystemUser getLastUpdateUser() {
        return lastUpdateUser;
    }

    /**
     * Sets last modified by audit user.
     */
    public void setLastUpdateUser(SystemUser lastUpdateUser) {
        this.lastUpdateUser = lastUpdateUser;
    }

    /**
     * Gets last modified audit date.
     */
    public DateTime getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    /**
     * Sets last modified audit date.
     */
    public void setLastUpdated(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        setCreated(dateTime);

    }

    @Override
    public SystemUser getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastUpdateUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedBy(SystemUser systemUser) {
        lastUpdateUser = systemUser;

    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        lastUpdated = dateTime;

    }

    public String getExternalIdentifier() {
        return externalIdentifier;
    }

    public void setExternalIdentifier(String externalIdentifier) {
        this.externalIdentifier = externalIdentifier;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question - had the same issue, and this presentation lays it all out quite nicely.  Always fun to check the superclass for easter eggs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [javadoc of AbstractPersistable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html#isNew--): it has a method `isNew()` returning a boolean. That's why Jackson puts a `new` attribute in your JSON.

You could easily ihnore this property by overriding the `isNew()` method and annotating it with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: I came across this issue when trying to implement a $resource CRUD angularjs application via ReST call to a Spring MVC back-end.  Overriding isNew pulls out the "new" property on the resulting JSON response.  Needless to say object.new does not jive with any browser.  Not sure why any API would go anywhere near setting a property in any modern OO language to "new".  Thanks JB Nizet, saved me at least hours of frustration!